# "No hurries. No worries" - could we say "No hurries nor worries"?

Tags: conjunctions, negation, ellipsis

I was recently commenting some answers in Stack Overflow when one person said something to which I replied:

> No hurries. No worries.

I have seen both "no hurries" and "no worries" many times, but I doubted on what was the best way to use them together: would it be correct to say as follows?

> No hurries nor worries

I would say this as a way to contract the "neither you have to hurry neither to worry".

Comment: It's grammatically correct as far as it goes, but it's so un-idiomatic that it looks very strange.  The phrase is usually "no **hurry**", singular, because it's short for "there is no hurry", singular,  because you are only in one hurry at a time.  But you could have more than one worry at a time!  In any case, it sounds non-fluent and non-idiomatic to use them together with "nor".

Comment: @stangdon oh, thanks! First of all, I thought it was _no hurries_, so thanks for that. Secondly, is there any way to "merge" both _no hurry_ and _no worries_ in a single sentence into something idiomatic?

Comment: In the context of just four words, the notion of "a single sentence" is pretty meaningless: whether you point with a period or a comma is more about indicating rhythm and prosody than about syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Neither hurries nor worries* doesn't to my ear have the sort of rhythm you want in a catchphrase. And although *worry* is commonly used as a count noun—you may have many *worries* weighing on your mind—this is very rare with *hurry*: it's almost always a quality ascribed to persons or activities rather than an instance of hurrying.<sup>†</sup>

*No hurry, no worry* sounds better to me. It might have two meanings, depending on the context:

- There is no need for your hearer either to hurry or to worry—you don't need immediate response or action. In other words, "Don't hurry, and don't worry".
- Your hearer should avoid hurrying, because that will avoid future problems. In other words, "If you don't hurry, you won't worry".

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Except in US football jargon, where *a hurry* is an instance of transitive *hurrying*: rushing the quarterback so aggressively you compel him to pass the ball before his receivers are in good position to catch it.</sub>

Comment: +1 I would add that the second interpretation of *No hurry, no worry* follows some other similar idiomatic phrases, like *No woman, no cry* (you'll be happier if you don't have romantic entanglements); *No harm, no foul* (if no actual damage is done, then no punishment is needed); *No shirt, no shoes, no service* (If you aren't wearing a shirt and shoes then you will not be served); etc.

Comment: @1006a What I was thinking of was another one: *no pain, no gain*.

Comment: Yes, that too! It even rhymes, like the OP's sentence.